# Iterating over Numpy Array rows in python even with 1 row / 2 columns array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, row, enumerate

I am trying to iterate over the rows of a numpy array. The array may consist of two columns and multiple rows like `[[a, b], [c, d], ...]`, or sometimes a single row like `[a, b]`.

For the one-dimensional array, when I use `enumerate` to iterate over rows, python yields the individual elements `a` then `b` instead of the complete row `[a, b]` all at once.

How to I iterate the one-dimensional case in the same way as I would the 2D case?

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @bhristov. Honestly, this is a pretty clearly specified problem. I did edit it a bit to conform to modern American usage a bit though.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thank you, your edit made it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy iterates over the first dimension no matter what. Check the shape before you iterate.

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 2])
>>> x.ndim
1

>>> y = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
>>> y.ndim
2
```

Probably the simplest method is to always wrap in a call to `np.array`:

```
>>> x = np.array(x, ndmin=2, copy=False)
>>> y = np.array(y, ndmin=2, copy=False)
```

This will prepend a dimension of shape 1 to your array as necessary. It has the advantage that your inputs don't even have to be arrays, just something that can be converted to an array.

Another option is to use the [`atleast_2d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html) function:

```
>>> x = np.atleast_2d(x)
```

All that being said, you are likely sacrificing most of the benefits of using numpy in the first place by attempting a vanilla python loop. Try to vectorize your operation instead.

Comment: Thank a lot for your feedback. For that, I can't vectorize that.

Comment: @EdouardDKP. You can post another question if you like. You might be surprised what you can vectorize if you just know how.